# React DnD triggers mouse event handlers after state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am building a simple script to let someone sort a list of items using Drag & Drop.  The items successfully sort, but after the drag operation has ended, it triggers the onMouseEnter events of the item that took its original place.

[image: ReactDnD Issue]

Here's some simple code to replicate: https://codesandbox.io/s/m33o3x610p

Is this a bug in React-DnD?  Does React-DND trigger mouse events after state changes?

PS: I am able to bypass it by conditionally delaying the onMouseEnter event, but this is poor practice.

Comment: Isn't the mouse over it?

Comment: No, when i move an object (e.g. "Testing 8"), the mouse moves along with it.  When i drop it, it correctly drops, but the hover triggers on totally different object ("Testing 6")...the object that happened to replace the location of the original object